# The import org.eclipse.jface cannot be resolved in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse-plugin, compiler-errors, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-luna

I wrote a plugin five years ago and it was correct (with no compiler error) in all version of Eclipse until **Luna**. When I updated my eclipse to Luna, I got two compiler errors.

The error is because of these two import statements. (The import org.eclipse.jface cannot be resolved, The import org.eclipse.swt cannot be resolved)

```
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
```

I wanted to add two new dependencies to the plugin file, but I could not find any relevent. For example, I could not find org.eclipse.jface.resource in dependency page.

Does anyone have any idea why the plugin works in **Kepler**, but has the above compiler errors in **Luna**?

Comment: Be sure to go to your Target Platform preferences and reset them for the versions in Luna.

Comment: The dependencies for these are `org.eclipse.jface` and `org.eclipse.swt`

Comment: Yes, but the versions and files they point to on disk might be out of date in the preferences, thus "missing".

Comment: I could not find org.eclipse.jface and org.eclipse.swt in dependency page. I can see other packages from jface such org.eclipse.jface.source, but not org.eclipse.jface.

Comment: I updated all dependencies with their new ones, but again it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this page can help you:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Create_the_Eclipse_SWT.2FJFace_Project

Sections: **Identify the Required External JAR Files for SWT and JFace** and also **Add the org.eclipse.swt Project to Your Java Project**

Comment: The web page helps me to solve the compiler error. But Still I do not know why I do not have this problem for previous version of Eclipse. The error only happens in Luna.

Comment: @user3623718: I am having the same problem. What exactly on the web page did solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add you eclipse plugins directory to it in Target Platform. All problem will be resolved